# How to use count distinct in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a sql:

```
select field2, count(distinct field1) from table group by field2;
```

How to achieve this sql in pymongo?

Comment: Start by reading the MongoDB documentation. You can't blindly convert SQL statements to MongoDB queries nor should you expect SO to do it for you.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish these kinds of queries with the pymongo driver by using the `.group()` function.

`db.table.group(["field1"], {}, {"count":0},"function(o, p){p.count++}" )`

This will group together distinct values of "field1" and increment a counter to track the number of occurrences of each.

Answer (score 3):

I've found this resource to be very helpful when working on doing conversions from SQL to Mongo [SQL to Mongo Mapping Chart](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart)

In this case you would be looking like something similar to:

```
db.users.group({key: {age: true},
initial: {count: 0}, 
reduce: function (obj, prev) { prev.count++;} } )
```

Since you have a bit more complex logic here you need to use the reduce function. Honestly you should read a bit more into this to fully understand exactly what is going on here. [Map Reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce)